# making an alert() if checkbox is checked in html using js

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, checkbox

so i wrote an html page just for testing but i cant get the script work and its just says the alert and checks the checkbox but i wanna that when i check the checkbox the alert will appear. here's the code (without style.css).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<p class="head1">SOME HEADING</p>
</header>
<div class="div1">
<h1>AN HEADING</h1>
<form>
<ul>
<li><input class="in1" id="checkboxid" type="checkbox">First Box</li>
<li><input class="in1" type="checkbox">Second Box</li>
<li><input class="in1" type="checkbox">Third Box</li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>
<script>
if (document.getElementById("checkboxid").checked = true) {
alert("You checked the first box.");
}
else {
alert("you didnt checked the box.");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Learn about event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake, you are using `=` instead of `===`. Also, you can consider using a function `change()` that will be fired up when you first checkbox is checked or not.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<p class="head1">SOME HEADING</p>
</header>
<div class="div1">
<h1>AN HEADING</h1>
<form>
<ul>
<li><input class="in1" id="checkboxid" type="checkbox" onclick="change()">First Box</li>
<li><input class="in1" type="checkbox">Second Box</li>
<li><input class="in1" type="checkbox">Third Box</li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>
<script>
function change(){
  if (document.getElementById("checkboxid").checked === true) {
    alert("You checked the first box.");
  }
  else {
    alert("you didnt checked the box.");
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh ok thx, i fixed it now and used a function so it'll work only when i check the box and not on page load, thx to Swakeert Jain telling my question is a duplicate from another question (see comment on the question). so here's what i got now: `function checkbox() {
if (document.getElementById("checkboxid").checked === true) {
alert("You checked the first box.");
}
else {
alert("you didnt checked the box.");
}
}`

Comment: @IsraelShevkolenko, Great, you solved it! Happy coding! You can mark the answer as accepted and upvote it.